# Why is my inherited method outputting Base class' member instead of derived class' member

Tags: c++, inheritance, datamember

I am trying to print the member 'age' from the Mum class which inherits the method print_age() from Dad, but it is printing the member 'age' from Dad's class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

  class Dad
  {
  protected:
    int age = 59;

  public:
    void print_age() { cout << age << endl; }
  };

  class Mum : public Dad
  {
  protected:
    int age = 54;
  };

  Mum m;
  m.print_age();
}
```

This outputs *59* when I want it to output *54*

Comment: Why do you think it should print `54`? The output of `59` is correct … (think of what `age` is referring to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, only *member functions* can be overridden, not *member variables*. As a result, when you write

```
  class Mum : public Dad
  {
  protected:
    int age = 54;
  };
```

C++ interprets this as "I know that `Dad` already has an `int` field called `age` whose value is 59, but I'd like to also add a different `int` field called `age` whose value is 59 and that only lives in the `Mum` class." Stated differently, you aren't replacing the old value of `age` with a new one; you're declaring a new variable that `Dad` doesn't know about that coincidentally has the same name as one of the variables from `Dad`.

Now, why does that mean that you see the value `59`? Let's look at the code for `Dad`:

```
  class Dad
  {
  protected:
    int age = 59;

  public:
    void print_age() { cout << age << endl; }
  };
```

In `print_age`, C++ sees the use of `age` and then needs to decide what to do. It has no idea that there's a `Mum` class that will be defined later that will also independently create a `protected` `int` called `age`. Rather, it sees `age` defined in `Dad` and says "oh, that must be what `age` refers to" and uses that value. As a result, when you call

```
   m.print_age();
```

you see the value of `age` in `Dad` rather than the value of `age` in `Mum`. It's because the code for `print_age` is written in the `Dad` class, which can't see anything in `Mum`.

If you'd like to make it so that `Mum` has age 59, you could do this instead:

```
  class Mum : public Dad
  {
  public:
     Mum() {
        age = 54;
     }
  };
```

Here, the constructor says "when you create a `Mum` object, go find the `age` data member and set it equal to 54." This means that there's one single `age` variable, which defaults to 59 but is explicitly set to 54 in the `Mum` constructor. Now, calling `print_age` will print out 54 because the code for `Dad::print_age` looks at the `age` variable that was just set.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The function is called from `Dad`. Inside `Dad`, `Dad`'s age would be the output.